# Android wear in app purchases

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, wear-os

I have an app which offers in app purchases of watch faces for Android Wear.

The new API however seems to push all faces *implementing the CanvasWatchFaceService to the Android Wear application* - perpetually making all my paid faces free!

1. **How can I still allow users to perform in-app purchases without them directly being able to access the faces within Android Wear?**

Needless to say if the purchase is successful, only then I would want the watch face to be visible in the Android Wear gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Since watchfaces are registered as a service (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html), and there is no option to register services programmatically. I don't see any option to offer them as in-app payment feature.

From my point of view you got three options:

1. Make a demo version with less features (free / pro version)
2. Put a "this is a demo version" text on the watch if it wasn't purchased (I wouldn't recommend this solution since you will get bad ratings for sure)
3. Wrap each developed watchface in it's own app and publish it as a payed app